# How to git patch the whole branch/tag in git to apply it on another repository which is not updated?

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo with branch named development with tag v1.14,
I have the same repo at different location which is out of internet connection/ slow connectivity.

I need to create a patch for the development branch and mail the patch so that it can be applied.

My workout :

```
git format-patch --root v1.14 --stdout > ../git-for-mail/patches
```

At Remote Repo I execute this command:

```
git am --ignore-whitespace  < ~/workspace/git-for-mail/patches
```

I get these error:

```
error: .gitignore: already exists in index
error: Gemfile: already exists in index
error: db/migrate/20140819091734_add_customer_number_to_location.rb: already exists in    working directory
Patch failed at 0001 Implemented PC-81 & PC-77.
Applying: Adding Comments for PC-77
error: patch failed: lib/kitting/app/controllers/kitting/kit_copies_controller.rb:13
error: lib/kitting/app/controllers/kitting/kit_copies_controller.rb: patch does not apply
error: patch failed: lib/kitting/app/controllers/kitting/locations_controller.rb:6
error: lib/kitting/app/controllers/kitting/locations_controller.rb: patch does not apply
Patch failed at 0002 Adding Comments for PC-77
```

Kindly let me know if there is any alternate solution or a hack to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance !!!

Santosh Mohanty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the `--root` flag, your `format-patch` command is generating patches [all the way back to the first commit in the repository](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-format-patch):

> ### Examples
>
> Extract all commits that lead to origin since the inception of the project:
>
> ```
> $ git format-patch --root origin
> ```

This causes Git to try to create commits that already exist on your remote. Instead, figure out what the latest commit is on your remote repository, and create patches from that point on.

In the remote repository:

```
git rev-parse --short HEAD  # Outputs something like 1234abc
```

In your local repository, generate patches from the hash you just got up to your tag:

```
git format-patch 1234abc..v1.14 --stdout > ../git-for-mail/patches
```

Finally, apply your patches to the remote repository using your original command.